# GitHub: Continuous integration to Azure with organization repository

Tags: azure, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-organizations

I'm developing a game. GitHub as my source vault; Azure is my deployment platform. I created an [organization](https://github.com/monmamo) for my game, since I hope it will eventually be more than just me working on it. There are two separate repositories within the organization, each of which will deploy to a separate Azure website. I need to link each repository to its respective website.

I know how to navigate to the Continuous Deployment blade, connect GitHub to it, and select my project and branch. However, the Choose Project blade doesn't list any of the organization projects, only my own. I change the authorization, but the authorizer requires me to log into a GitHub account. An organization isn't an account and doesn't have a direct login (as far as I can tell).

I hope that there is a way to do this, because this will be a big problem for me if I cannot link these repositories to their deployment destinations.

Comment: Do you have a user account on GitHub or just the organization? I have an organization in which I've added my GitHub user account to the members list, then you can follow the workflow. Here is a walkthrough: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Tutorials/Github-Continuous-Delivery-in-the-Preview-Portal

Answer (score 4):

I have a blog post going over this in detail.

You can find it here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/08/10/using-app-service-web-apps-continuous-deployment-with-github-organizations/

Including it here as well for convenience as well:

[image: Azure Preview Portal]
Start with the **Azure Preview Portal** by **authenticating** to **GitHub** with your **GitHub account** that has access to the **organizations** you want to use.

[image]
From **GitHub** go to your user **Settings**.

[image]
Select **Applications (1)** from the **Personal Settings** section and click on the **Azure Management Portal (2)** form the **Authorized Applications** list.

[image]
This will bring up the authorized application permissions and will include a list of **Organization access** for the organization you belong to.
If you are an **Owner** for the organization you will be able to **Grant access** directly from here, however if you are not an owner you will be able to **Request Access** and an **Owner** will need to approve it.

[image]
Once this access has been granted for the organization you will be able to select it when configuring **Continuous Deployment**.
If you want to see a demo of this in action you can check out this Channel 9 video: [GitHub continuous delivery in the Azure Preview Portal](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Tutorials/Github-Continuous-Delivery-in-the-Preview-Portal)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fixed it, now you have the full instructions ;)

Comment: Neat! It's cool that you have a blog post that directly answers his question, and it makes for a great Stack Overflow answer too!

Comment: Make sure the user has Admin access on the repository you're trying to deploy from. This helped me see the organization in the Azure portal, but not the repository until I had admin access.